# Is Expression Blend available for windows desktop applications?

Tags: c#, expression, desktop-application, expression-blend

I am in love with expression blend whilst I was working with windows phone 7.

Now I am working on a windows desktop application and I would like to design the form using expression blend.

Is Expression Blend available for desktop applications or is it solely for phone?

Comment: Why do you think I posted a question here then?

Answer (score 1):

Expression Blend is for `Windows Presentation Foundation` and `Silverlight`. So, if you want to use WPF for desktop apps development, then expression blend is the way.....

Answer (score 0):

I would like to get that working as well.  There is not option in VS to Open in Blend when you are building a desktop application.  Blend For VS 2013 does not give you the option to make a desktop application either.